# ScrolledComposite inside TabItem

Tags: java, scroll, tabs, widget, swt

I am trying to create a scrollable `TabItem` inside a `TabFolder`, using a `ScrolledComposite`. My window has two tabs and the second one (`tab2`) should have scroll bars and be scrollable.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Control control = super.createContents(parent);

    TabFolder folder = new TabFolder((Composite) dialogArea, SWT.TOP);
    TabItem tab1 = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    tab1.setText("Tab One");
    Composite c1 = createMyFirstComposite(folder);
    tab1.setControl(c1);
    TabItem tab2 = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    tab2.setText("Tab Two");

    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(folder, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    Composite c2 = (Composite) createMySecondComposite(folder);
    sc.setContent(c2);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(c2.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    sc.setShowFocusedControl(true);
    tab2.setControl(c2);

    return control;
}
```

Unfortunately the content of the `tab2` is not scrollable and has no scroll bars. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `setControl` for tab 2 should be the scrolled composite, so:

```
tab2.setControl(sc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Unfortunately it doesn't show any content, if I change to `tab2.setControl(sc)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to say more. At a guess you have not set a Layout on the Composites - you must set a Layout on every Composite.